# get image from an external weblink through its attributes (id, class) using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get an image from an external weblink(like http://www.alpha.com/beta/?a=some_url_encoding ) through its css id, class and by applying javascript / jquery get methods? can some body help me with this?

Comment: What do its "css id" and "class" have to do with getting an image?

Comment: the image link is randomly generated each time...

Comment: so, to grab the image link I think the only possiblity is through its id/class which are constant? Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: It sounds like you are thinking about getting references to images that are already in the page.  If so, yes you can do that by using the value of the id or class attribute in the `<img>` tag.  But that has nothing to do with getting "an image from an external weblink", which we understand as "load on image with javascript after the page has loaded".  In the latter case, css id and class have nothing to do with that.  So which is it?

Comment: hey 150PoundsOfDonamite , the problem is like for example I want to put google logo in http://www.google.com/ on my own webpage not by downloading the image but through javascript / jquery get methods...

Answer (score 0):

A image on some external domain doesn't have a class or id until you've added it to the DOM.

You could create an image tag with jQuery and append it to some existing DOM element:

```
$("<img src='http://alpha.com/beta/?a=some_url_encoding' />").appendTo(".existing");
```

Comment: hey rjmackay , here the link is not the image link, its the link of the webpage in which image is contained...

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you would do this:

```
$.get('http://www.alpha.com/beta/?a=some_url_encoding', function(data) {
    var images = $(data).find('img');
    //...
});
```

However, you can't. To do so would be a cross-origin AJAX request, which is forbidden in order to prevent XSS.

Comment: hey man, why can't I? many people make extensions / add-ons by getting sources from external web pages right!

Comment: @tsndiffopera: Extensions are a different matter. You didn't say that was what you were making. Typically, the browser grants extensions elevated privileges, allowing them to make approved cross-origin requests.